# Update columns when value is numeric in tsql

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, datetime, sql-update

I want to normalize date fields from an old badly designed db dump. I now need to update every row, where the datefield only contains the year.

```
update table set date = '01.01.' + date
where date like '____' and isnumeric(date) = 1 and date >= 1950
```

But this will not work, because sql does not do short circuit evaluation of boolean expressions. Thus I get an error "error converting nvarchar '01.07.1989' to int"

Is there a way to work around this? The column also contains strings with a length of 4, which are not numbers (`????`, `5/96`, `70/8`, etc.) the table *only* has 60000 rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could always do a subquery

```
update table set date = '01.01.' + date
where id in(

   select id from table
   where date like '____' and isnumeric(date)

)
and convert(int, date) >= 1950
```

Answer (score 1):

How about just enclosing 1950 in single quotes?

I ran a quick test:

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE (Date NVARCHAR(20))
INSERT @Table 
SELECT '2010' 
UNION ALL 
SELECT '2009' 
UNION ALL 
SELECT '01.07.1989' 
UNION ALL 
SELECT '1951'
UNION ALL
SELECT '1940'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Some Text'

UPDATE @Table
SET Date = '01.01.' + date
WHERE date LIKE '____' AND ISNUMERIC(date) = 1 AND date>='1950'

SELECT * FROM @Table
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe add a new field to store actual datetime Value:

```
alter table [Table] add [RealDate] datetime;
update [Table] set [RealDate] = cast([Date] as datetime) where isdate([Date]) = 1
```

Comment: i need to parse as many dates as possible from the old data, then i do it this way already